# Base class static method using constants of derived class

Tags: c#

I'm a bit new to c#. Is the following pattern viable or do I need to rethink things:

```
public abstract class Foo{
    abstract const Format Format;
    public static GetFormat(){
        return <Format configured by derived class> 
    }
}

public class JsonFoo:Foo{
    const Format Format = Format.JSON;
}

public class XmlFoo:Foo{
    const Format Format = Format.XML;
}
```

I've tried to resolve it several ways buy I always run in to static can not be abstract/virtual etc.

(The code above is just to illustrate the problem)

Edit:

So i want to build an abstract base class with most of my logic, and then create light weight derived classes. All most all of the operations are identical but with minor differences (such as using a different format (the real case is accessing different DbSets on a common DbContext)).

Some of the operations are very similar (in the DbSet context, find object by id, find all etc...)

Comment: No such thing as abstract static, or abstract const.

Comment: I know, that's the problem :P, Looking for a way to solve the problem posed above or another design pattern

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Have JsonFoo and XmlFoo each provide their own implementation of GetFormat() ?

Comment: You haven't actually stated what problem you think the thing that doesn't exist is solving.

Comment: Static members aren't really part of any inheritance structure.  What conceptually are you trying to do?  There's likely a way to do it, but I'm not really seeing the intent here.

Comment: @SverkerSbrg: Why does any of it need to be `static`?  The concepts you're using work fine on instance members.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've done strange construction. You should write something like:

```
public enum Format{XML,JSON}
public abstract class Foo
{
    public abstract Format Format { get; }
}
public class JsonFoo : Foo
{
    public override Format Format
    {
        get { return Format.JSON; }
    }
}
public class XmlFoo : Foo
{
    public override Format Format
    {
        get { return Format.XML; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probobly, I've done most of my coding in python. So the answer is impossible with static?

Comment: **Absoutely impossible** with a static or const member.

Comment: So for a DbContext.<insert dbSet here> the answer would be to move the "static" behaviour such as find all. To a Factory and keep non static content in this class?

Comment: @SverkerSbrg I didn't see any DbContext here. Let us see full code.